# Borrar un objeto (que está almacenado en una lista fuera de la clase), desde adentro del objeto

Tags: python, tkinter

Creo una clase, después instancio varios objetos y los guardo en una lista. A su vez el objeto tiene definida una función que lo elimina mediante `.destroy()`: quiero que al eliminar el objeto se elimine también el elemento de la lista.
El código es:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Miclase:
    def __init__(self):
        
        mi_frame = tk.LabelFrame(ventana,height = 30, width =20, text = 'Mi Texto')
        mi_frame.pack(fill='x')


        def eliminarme():
            mi_frame.destroy()

        miboton = tk.Button(mi_frame, text = 'Eliminar', command = eliminarme)
        miboton.pack()



ventana = tk.Tk()

def imprimir():
    print(mi_lista)

#imprime por consola los elementos de la lista para poder ver que paso si se eliminan o no
otro_boton = tk.Button(ventana, text = 'Imprime', command = imprimir)
otro_boton.pack()


a = Miclase()
b = Miclase()
c = Miclase()

mi_lista = list()

mi_lista.append(a)
mi_lista.append(b)
mi_lista.append(c)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    ventana.mainloop()
```

No encuentro cómo hacer que, al pulsar el botón que destruye el objeto, este se quite de la lista.

Cualquier idea será bienvenida.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PPelCan se me ocurre que una posible solución es pasar el parametro self a la variable 'mi_frame' para que la clase tenga una referencia al objeto frame y posteriormente poder eliminarlo de la lista.

Algo como esto:

```py
class Miclase:
    def __init__(self):
        
        self.mi_frame = tk.LabelFrame(ventana,height = 30, width =20, text = 'Mi Texto')
        mi_frame = self.mi_frame
        mi_frame.pack(fill='x')
        def eliminarme():
            _lista = globals()["mi_lista"]
            for object in _lista:
                if object.mi_frame == mi_frame:
                    mi_frame.destroy()
                    index= _lista.index(object)
                    _lista.pop(index)
                    print(len(_lista))


        miboton = tk.Button(mi_frame, text = 'Eliminar', command = eliminarme)
        miboton.pack()
```

Comment: Hola CalumRakk. Es exactamente lo que necesitaba, te agradezco muchisimo tu ayuda,

Comment: Si la respuesta te ayudo @PPelCan seria genial que la marcarás como 'correcta' y así tú puedas ayudar a otros en el futuro a encontrar esta solución

Comment: es con el tilde verde no? .Gracias